# What does "pn" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

A user created a post seeking for help at https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/pe10zj/looking_to_pay_people_to_teach_me_rust/.

Someone replied:

> I might be able to help, hit me up.

And the user replied with:

> pn

What does "pn" mean here? Can't find it in dictionary. Urbandictionary has an entry that states it means "goodbye", but it seems doesn't fit in this context. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is based on a simple error by the author, and not an aspect of correct English in current use.

Comment: Come on, don't do that. You should understand that for non-native English speakers, it's not easy to identify cases like this. Things you take for granted sometimes seem hard to me.

Comment: It's not targeted at you, it should be closed for future readers.  I'll up vote this question. It's a good question. It just can't be answered in the context of Learning English. This question can't be useful to others unless it is a common error.  It's not.  The answer can only be "It's a mistake". Sure there is no way for a learner to know that so the question is good (+1) but not useful for the future (vtc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an error or typo for 'pm' or 'PM' (private message). Not everyone on Reddit is a native English speaker/writer, or even bothered about accuracy. See earlier post by that person:

> TheRealEfte OP · 2h hmm i am not sure that this will be a good match
> but i **pn'ed** you with to just talk a bit about it. s

**Do NOT expect good English on Reddit!**

> PM (noun)
> INTERNET & TELECOMS
> informal abbreviation for private
> message: a message sent on a social media website that only the person
> it is sent to can see:
>
> *I sent you a PM yesterday. Did you get it?*
>
> PM (verb)
> INTERNET & TELECOMS
> informal abbreviation for private
> message: to send someone a private message on a social media website:
>
> *PM me if you have any questions.*

[PM abbreviation (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pm)

Comment: Thank you for reminding! Since I'm not a native English speaker, sometimes I suppose English speaking people are all good at it, which is not. Thanks again for the answer!

Comment: "DM" meaning "*direct* message" is also used on some sites, notably Instagram.